# How do I make a button execute a function once?

Tags: python, button, arraylist, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am currently working on a keypad that connects to the raspberry pi. Each button when pressed needs to append a string to a list once and then restart the loop so the next input can be placed. The code looks like this:

```
message = [] #final list will be stored here
loop = 0 #determines the position of each number inputted
while True:
  if (GPIO.input(12) == GPIO.HIGH) and (GPIO.input(19) == GPIO.HIGH): #the character pad works in an array, when 2 "buttons" are pressed, they correspond do a location on the pad
    message.insert(loop, "1") #inserts the number into the list
    loop = loop + 1
  if (GPIO.input(12) == GPIO.HIGH) and (GPIO.input(15) == GPIO.HIGH):
    messege.insert(loop, "4")
    loop = loop + 1
  #this repeats for the other 14 buttons however the code is the same
```

if the button for "1" is pressed, and then "4" is pressed, the output for this code is supposed to look as such:

```
['1' '4']
```

however, the output looks like this:

```
['1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1...]
```

is there a way to make each button activate once per press?

The buttons in this code are all set up in pud_down

Comment: What you need here is called "edge detection".  You need to maintain the current state of the inputs, and when the states CHANGE from what you understand, that's when you take action.  Remember the GPIO lines will stay asserted as long as the buttons are pressed, and they will be pressed for many, many loops.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an object-oriented approach. You could create a `Button` class. Each button can either be in a `pressed` or `released` state. Whenever a button is initially pressed, it appends a message to the class variable `Button.messages`. The same button will not append another message until it has been released. In the main polling loop we iterate over all buttons and either press or release them, depending on which pins are high:

```
class Button:

    messages = []

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.is_pressed = False

    def hold(self):
        if not self.is_pressed:
            Button.messages.append(value)
            self.is_pressed = True

    def release(self):
        self.is_pressed = False


buttons = {
    (12, 19): Button("1"),
    (12, 15): Button("4"),
    # ...
}

row_pins = (12, 13, 14) # You'll have to change these. I don't know what these values should be
col_pins = (19, 15, 10) # You'll have to change these. I don't know what these values should be

while True:
    for row in row_pins:
        for col in col_pins:
            button = buttons[(row, col)]
            (button.release, button.hold)[all((GPIO.input(pin) for pin in (row, col)))]()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```python
message = [] #final list will be stored here
loop = 0 #determines the position of each number inputted
val i = 0
val k = 0
bool canPressAgain =true
while True:
  if (GPIO.input(i) == GPIO.LOW) and (GPIO.input(k) == GPIO.LOW):
    canPressAgain=true;
  if (GPIO.input(12) == GPIO.HIGH) and (GPIO.input(19) == GPIO.HIGH): 
    #the character pad works in an array, when 2 "buttons" are pressed, they correspond do a location on the pad
    i = 12
    k = 19
    message.insert(loop, "1") #inserts the number into the list
    loop = loop + 1
  if (GPIO.input(12) == GPIO.HIGH) and (GPIO.input(15) == GPIO.HIGH):
    i = 12
    k = 15
    messege.insert(loop, "4")
    loop = loop + 1
  canPressAgain = false; #Put this at the end of all 'if' statements
  #this repeats for the other 14 buttons however the code is the same
```

Comment: What language is that supposed to be?  It looks like a combination of C++, Python, and Javascript.  Could you maybe choose ONE language and try your answer again?

Comment: @TimRoberts Edited. The main takeaway a reader is supposed to have is that by default a 'canPressAgain' boolean is false;  the values i & k are always set to the last button pressed's input variables.
Each loop, if the button with the i&k input variables is off (After being in a on state, which is required to set i and k), then another button can be pressed and it's value added.

I hope this clears things up Tim :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like this.  The key is not to evaluate the states unless you know something has changed:

```
message = [] #final list will be stored here
loop = 0 
states = {
    12: GPIO.LOW,
    15: GPIO.LOW,
    19: GPIO.LOW
}
while True:
    change = False
    for line in (12,15,19):
        if GPIO.input(line) != states[line]:
            states[line] = GPIO.input(line)
            change = True

    if change:
        change = False
        if states[12]==GPIO.HIGH and states[19]==GPIO.HIGH:
            message.insert(loop, "1") #inserts the number into the list
            loop = loop + 1
        if states[12]==GPIO.HIGH and states[15]==GPIO.HIGH:
            messege.insert(loop, "4")
            loop = loop + 1
```